# problems with deleting document in mongodb using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I try to delete document in mongodb using php, I it fails and I get a waring:

> Warning: MongoCollection::remove() expects parameter 2 to be boolean, array given

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$db = $mongo->test; 
$collection = $db->subscribers;
$collection->remove(array( 'LISTID' => 49));
```

Could you please tell me what causes an error?
I phpinfo() shows:

```
mongo
MongoDB Support enabled
Version     1.0.4+

Directive   Local Value Master Value
mongo.allow_persistent  On  On
mongo.auto_reconnect    On  On
mongo.chunk_size    262144  262144
mongo.cmd   $   $
mongo.default_host  localhost   localhost
mongo.default_port  27017   27017
mongo.utf8  1   1
```

It's strange, the documentation say the function looks like:

```
public mixed MongoCollection::remove ( array $criteria [, array $options = array() ] )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using a very old version. From the manual

> 1.0.5  Changed second parameter to an array of options. Pre-1.0.5, the second parameter was a boolean indicating the "justOne" option and there was no safe option.

Either upgrade or change your code to

```
$collection->remove(array('LISTID' => 49), false);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me if it's possible to find a newer version of mongodb extension for php vc6 for windows?

Comment: user366534, you really should upgrade your PHP to something that uses VS9 though. The VS6 builds are no longer supported. The VS6 compiler is 14 years! old.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the remove options:

```
$collection->remove(array('type' => 94), array("justOne" => true));
```

for more info, see [the online manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.remove.php)